# Нью-эйджерский или нью-эйджеский?

Tags: словообразование

ДД! КАК ВЕРНО:
нью-эйджерский или нью-эйджеский?

Answer (score 1):

Есть философия нью эйдж, от неё прилагательное нью-ейджеский, есть последователи философии - нью-эйджеры, от них прилагательное нью-эйджерский

Comment: Но я бы предпочитала говорить Философия нью эйдж, музыка в стиле нью эйдж, не так уж и прижились эти существительные, чтобы ещё и прилагательные от них образовывать на русский манер.